# how to use check box list inside Ionic Action Sheet?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view

I'm new to an ionic framework and its components. I am creating a mobile app using Ionic Framework. I like the UX of ActionSheet (Coming up from the bottom with a list of buttons) but it comes only with options of adding buttons. I want to know whether we can use check box list inside Ionic ActionSheet? I have googled it but I didn't find any useful link to do that. Please help me. Thanks in advance.